# What does それだけかかってしまうんですね　in this conversation mean?

Tags: translation, particle-だけ

I found this conversation from a Japanese learning website and I don't understand a phrase here. Please help!

Question: What does それだけかかってしまうんですね mean here?

Does だけ here imply that that the fee that varies from distance alone will cost you a lot already, not to mention other fees like...

> 電話で男の学生と引越し会社の人が話しています。
>
> 男：あっ、もしもし。あの、ちょっと急なんですが、来週東京から北海道に引っ
>   越したいんです。私、 学生なんですが、できるだけ安い引越しの方法ないかな
>   ぁって思ってるんですが。
>
> 女：いくつかプランがございますが、学生さんでしたら、学生パックという割安
>   なプランがございます。 ただ、大型家具がある場合には、別料金となります。
>
> 男：そうですか。ベッドとあと、大きめの本棚が二つあるんで。
>
> 女：ああ、そうしますと、かえって高くなりますね。
>
> 男：そうですか。
>
> 女：えっと、トラック便というのが、ご利用の多い一般的なプランなんですが、そうですね、お客様の 場合、北海道までということで、かなり距離がありますので、料金のほうも**それだけかかってしまうんですね**。むしろ、鉄道を利用した鉄道便を利用されたほうがお得になります。ただ、鉄道便ですと、荷物の扱いが若干荒い場合がございますので、壊れやすい電機製品ですとか、楽器などがある場合は、お勧めできないんですが。
>
> 男：そうですか。
>
> 女：それと、ほかに同じトラック輸送でも、「エコノミー便」と申しまして、ほかのお客様のお荷物と 一緒に運ばせていただく方法ですね。こちらですと、トラック便に比べて、4 割ほどお安くなりますが、 お荷物の到着までにお時間をいただきます。
>
> 男：へえ、そうですか。何日ぐらいかかるんですか。
>
> 女：そうですね。一週間程度でしょうか。同じ方面に運ぶ荷物が集まった時点で出発いたしますので、 そのときの状況によって変わってくるんですが。
>
> 男：そんなにかかるんじゃ、ちょっと困るよなぁ。...ううん、家具は多いけど、特別壊れやすいもの もないし、じゃあ。

Source: http://japanesetest4you.com/pdf/n1-listening-7.pdf

(I don't know whether the site creator is here at stackexchange or not,
but anyway thanks so much for the great resources. I hope I'm not doing
anything illegally. Just for educational purposes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This それだけ means "to that extent", "as much", "accordingly" or "correspondingly", referring to the long distance from Tokyo to Hokkaido. It can be rephrased as その(長い)距離に応じて.

だけ here is used in the same way as the "as much as ～" construction, as in 食べたら食べただけ太る, できるだけ頑張ります and 飲みたいだけ飲んでいい.

Examples:

- 食べたらそれだけ太る。
- 値段は高いが、それだけの価値がある。