# Does だけ necessarily carry a negative connotation?

Tags: words, particle-だけ

I was praised by my tutor for the progress I'd made myself thus far, but somehow the message just seemed to carry a strange negative connotation to me. Here's the part where I found a tad off:

> 今年二月から勉強して、**それだけ**の長文を書けるのはすごいことだとおもいます。

This is part of his reply after I reached out to him for an offer to be my tutor in conversation yesterday. I am fairly certain he wasn't being sarcastic or anything. There was absolutely no need to.

The reason why I find the message ostensibly negative is that I usually associate **だけ** with a sense of negative exclusiveness. Therefore, "**これだけの長文**" just reads like, "*an article only so long in length*" to me.

Am I being influenced by my understanding of **だけ**, especially how it usually translates to "*only*" in English? If not, is there a better way to rephrase this to avoid any confusion?

For example:

> こんな程度の長文を書けるのはすごい…

Is this somewhat better than using **だけ**?

ご教授をいただければ、ありがたく思います。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: FWIW: some examples of grammar points using だけ in a positive way: だけあって・だけに・ だけのことはある

Answer (score 2, accepted):

だけ is not necessarily negative, and this それだけ just means "that much" (or "that good" in this context).

Here are some related questions where だけ is not used in negative ways:

- [What's the role of だけの in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39555/5010)
- [Is 足りるだけ with a negative verb idiomatic?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57298/5010)
- [Meaning of それだけ in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15096/5010)
- [What does それだけかかってしまうんですね　in this conversation mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60416/5010)
- [Meaning of XばXだけY vs. XばXほどY](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55065/5010)

Contrary to your expectation, こんな程度/この程度 is usually used in negative or sarcastic remarks. (e.g., この程度の文章ではダメだ)

Comment: Just realized the question was yet another duplicate. I cannot believe I didn't find the posts you linked to. I think I've even read some of them before.